# Unity - DontDestroyOnLoad() or public static variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I'm pretty new into programming and was wondering if it makes more sense to initialize a game object with multiple variables i want to have in every scene (and not kill it with DontDestroyOnLoad() or to use public static variables? Is there any difference between those two methods?

Thanks for your time!

Pucks

Comment: I prefer a game object with a script as it will allow you to inspect the variables at run time.

Comment: Static variables are also ok but you lose control quickly and you need to reset everything manually. If you initialize many objects maybe look into object pooling if it is for instance a bullet or a tree.

Comment: @Iggy and VisDesign Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4):

There is no generic "better or worse" answer, they both have their own (vastly different) uses.

### DontDestroyOnLoad

`DontDestroyOnLoad()` will make it so your `GameObject` persist through screen loads, but they will still be *instantiated objects*, meaning they are an *instance* of an object. The data that the *instance* of the object holds will be gone when the object gets deleted, but its possible that there are *multiple instances* of the same object which each have their own values, and editing one instance doesn't influence the other.

Imagine you have two `GameObject`'s in your scene which both have the following `Person` script attached:
`Person.cs` script attached to them:

```cs
public class Person : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string firstName;
    public int age;

    void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        gameObject.name = firstName;
        IntroduceYourself();
    }

    private void IntroduceYourself()
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Hello, my name is {0}", firstName);
    }
}
```

Through the Unity inspector you can now name the first GameObject `Alice` and give her an age of `25`, while naming the second GameObject `Bob` and give him an age of `27`.

You now have two separate GameObjects which hold the same `Person` script, but have vastly different information contained in it. If we Alter Bob's age then Alice's age won't be affected because they are two completely separate *instances*.

Starting the scene will print the following to your console:

> Hello, my name is Bob
> Hello, my name is Alice

Because we call `DontDestroyOnLoad(this)` Alice and Bob won't get removed when switching between scenes either, making your data persist through scene loads.

### Public static variable

If we take a look over at the [MSDN definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) of `static` we get the following summary (emphasis mine):

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, **which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object**. The static modifier can be used to declare static classes. In classes, interfaces, and structs, you may add the static modifier to fields, methods, properties, operators, events, and constructors. The static modifier can't be used with indexers or finalizers. For more information, see Static Classes and Static Class Members.

The important part here is emphasized in bold "Rather than to a specific object" or in other words, not bound to the *instance* of an object (remember how I talked about different *instances* above).

If we have data that is bound to the type rather than to the instance of an object it means that if we change the data, the data gets changed for everything referring to it!

Let's modify the above `Person` script a little bit so it works with static (Notice that I now have to set the `firstName` and `age` in the `Start` (or somewhere else from code), as we can no longer set it through the inspector, because the data is no longer bound to that specific instance, but rather to the generic class!)

```cs
public class Person : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string firstName;
    public static int age;

    void Start()
    {
        firstName = "Bob";
        age = 25;

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        gameObject.name = firstName;
        IntroduceYourself();
    }

    private void IntroduceYourself()
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Hello, my name is {0}", firstName);
    }
}
```

If we now run the scene again, while still having our `GameObject`'s Alice and Bob with the `Person` script attached we will see the following printed in the console:

> Hello, my name is Bob
> Hello, my name is Bob

Does it become apparent why it is printing Bob twice now, instead of Bob and Alice? The reason is that we can only set the value of `firstName` to be one thing, and the moment we change it it changes everywhere because its not bound to a single instance anymore. if we wanted to change it to Alice we could add a piece of code like this:

```cs
public void ChangeName()
{
    Person.name = "Alice";
}
```

if we do this and print their introductions again the result will be

> Hello, my name is Alice
> Hello, my name is Alice

Here is a *simplified* visual example of instanced vs static (non instanced) data
[image]

### Summary

To answer your question more directly of whether you should use `static` variables or `DontDestroyOnLoad` **is it depends**.

- Do you only need *one instance* of the data (think about something like the IP address of your server, the user's username or the time of day etc) then you can use a static variable.
- Can there be *multiple instances* of your data (think about something
  like items in an inventory, multiple NPC's etc) then `DontDestroyOnLoad` is one of your options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Singleton Pattern* to achieve this.

```
class MyGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly MyGameObject Instance = new MyGameObject();

    private MyGameObject()
    {
        // Initialize your GameObject here.
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        // DoWork here.
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
class AnotherGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        MyGameObject.Instance.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this comment if i'd had enough reputation. You used readonly in your code, which i'm not 100% sure what it does but i guess it means you cant change the variables of the gameobject later (with other scripts etc) is that true?

Comment: Yes, readonly fields must be initialized in the constructor or in the field initializer as I did in the code sample. If you try to change reassign a value to the readonly field you get compiler error. I made it readonly so that other classes (scripts) can't assign a new object to the one and only `Instance`.